# Downloading 17.10 iso file is only giving me a text file

Tags: 17.10, iso

I am trying to get an iso to make a bootable usb on my linux machine. However when I try to download 17.10 it gives me a text file and not a disc image. I have tried to re download multiple times and it keeps doing the same thing over and over again.

Comment: @An0n mine isn't failing the download so I don't think it is the same thing.

Comment: Its just about the answer is the same. Check releases.ubuntu.com and make sure to download the iso file instead of the torrent or readme file.

Comment: I don't think the ISO (image or file you're downloading) is the issue, but the app/method you are using to download the file.  How are you downloading the file?  (for example I'd `wget` the file or just use the command `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10.1/ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso`. it sounds like whatever you're using to download has been told the file is ascii & is thus stripping off the non-ascii bits  (`kermit` & really old download tools used to do this when not in `binary` mode)

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct link to the ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10.1/ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Does that work for you?

Comment: No still a text file. I get two files when I hit download. One looks like a box and says `ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso.part`, the other is the text file that says `ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: My guess is the .iso file will remain empty (0 bytes) while the download is not finished, and your system is interpreting an empty file as a text file by sniffing.

Comment: This question seems to be about understanding how your web browser handles downloads, not really about Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay it's been like an hour though so I didn't know, thank you though i will wait longer

Comment: How big is that text file?

Comment: @Taylor Maybe you can order it online. That will be faster i think. Just kidding ;) Its getting late :-)